# Given a $n \times n$ matrix $P$, where $P^2=P$... What is wrong with my logic here?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have managed to 'prove' something incorrect and am trying to figure out where my logic is going wrong.  I'm pretty new to matrices so still getting to understand them.

Given an $n \times n$ matrix $P$ where $P^2=P$ and $I$ is the identity matrix:
$$P^2=P$$
$$PP=P$$
$$P^{-1}PP=P^{-1}P$$
$$IP=I$$
$$P=I$$

This seems to show that if $P^2=P$ then $P$ must be the identity.  While this case is true, other forms of $P$ also work.  For example:
$\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
1&0\\
\end{bmatrix}$

I feel like I am breaking a fundamental rule (or just making a really silly mistake). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What you seem to have proven is that $I$ is the only matrix that is both invertible and idempotent.

Comment: Since the zero matrix satisfies the property $P^2=P$, but is not invertible, you clearly see that assuming $P^{-1}$ exists is not justified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that $P$ in your case is not invertible. So assuming it has an inverse $P^{-1}$ and multiply it:

$$P^{-1}(P^2)=P^{-1}P$$

is an invalid step.

In the case that if $P$ is actually invertible, you have shown that it must be $I$